# I have to create tables where both have each as the foreign key . Which one should be created first

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

**DDL QUERY FOR CREATING MAINTENANCE_PROBLEM**

```
CREATE TABLE MAINTENANCE_PROBLEM (
MP_ID int primary key, 
MP_Description varchar2(250), 
Standard_Min_Labor_Cost number(4,2), 
Standard_Min_Labor_Hours int, 
PART_ID int,
Constraint MP_PART_ID_FK foreign key (PART_ID) references Vehicle_Part (PART_ID)
);
```

**DDL QUERY FOR CREATING VEHICLE_PART**

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_PART (
 PART_ID int primary key, 
PR_Description varchar2(250), 
PR_Cost number(4, 2), 
MP_ID int
Constraint VP_MP_ID_FK foreign key (MP_ID) references MAINTENANCE_PROBLEM (MP_ID)
);
```

Comment: Also--you really want a part to have a FK to a problem?  Have you thought that out thoroughly?  What if you have two problems that require the same part?  What if you have one problem that requires multiple parts?

Comment: In most cases such cyclic cross-reference is a result of analysis error.

Comment: what you call `vehicle_part` is in fact a "maintenance part", which should be a link table representing a many-to-many relationship between `maintenance_problem` and the parts table.

Comment: SQL Server has no "varchar2" datatype.

Comment: And ignoring the scripting issue, your relationship is required because your columns are not nullable. So which row do you insert first in order to create a new VEHICLE_PART? You need to give this schema additional consideration as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter--create both of them without the foreign key constraint, and then alter the tables to add the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In one maintenance , you may have multiple parts 
create a bridge table mp_id,part_id and create fk reference to this table from MAINTENANCE_PROBLEM, VEHICLE_PART